# Ansible - Configuring Supermicro servers via Redfish API

Tags: ansible

I plan to configure Supermicro servers via the Redfish API. Ansible provides the following modules for the Redfish API:

- [community.general.redfish_command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/redfish_command_module.html)
- [community.general.redfish_config](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/redfish_config_module.html)

Supermicro offers [this](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/other/RedfishRefGuide.pdf) Redfish Reference Guide, which describes its Redfish REST API in detail. However, the Ansible modules use some sort of *commands* to do the configurations, instead of URIs.

Can someone explain how to map the API options to the Ansible modules? E. g., how can I use the Ansible modules to set the hostname or to provide NTP settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in [U880D's helpful answer](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/17012/34805), you currently really have to dig down into the code to get working examples for Ansible's Redfish modules.

As a rule of thumb, I recommend to look at the info you can *get*, to get an idea of info you can probably *set*. Use both the Supermicro Redfish docs and the [redfish_info module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/redfish_info_module.html) to see what you can get. Be aware, the results are not identical and neither the former nor the latter is more complete than the other. The two examples below will highlight some differences.

The "commands" used by the Ansible modules cannot be found in the Supermicro/Redfish docs. They are synonyms for certain API URIs. You have to look them up in the code, e. g. [here](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/74c15c12418bf2f7e1dcac1a88657c8aefaeeb6d/plugins/modules/redfish_config.py#L368) and try to map them to the Supermicro/Redfish docs. Or dig down deeper to get to the functions that compose the URLs.

## Hostname

From the [Supermicro docs](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/other/redfish-ref-guide-html/Content/general-content/network-management.htm), you can see that there is a property called `HostName`:

> ```
> URI: /redfish/v1/Managers/1/EthernetInterfaces/1
> Method: GET
> Response: 200
> {
>     ...
>     "MTUSize": 1500,
>     "HostName": "local",
>     "FQDN": "local.supermicro.com",
>     ...
> }
> ```

FYI, querying the same info with Ansible, e. g.:

```yaml
- name: Get nic info
  community.general.redfish_info:
    category: Manager
    command: GetManagerNicInventory
    baseuri: "{{ baseuri }}"
    username: "{{ username }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
  register: result

- debug:
    var: result
```

will not return a "hostname" property (output omitted). So a win for the Supermicro docs...

Fortunately, you can still *set* the hostname with Ansible:

```yaml
- name: Set hostname
  community.general.redfish_config:
    category: Manager
    command: SetManagerNic
    nic_config:
      HostName: MyHostname
    baseuri: "{{ baseuri }}"
    username: "{{ username }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
```

## NTP

The [Supermicro docs](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/other/redfish-ref-guide-html/Content/general-content/bmc-configuration-examples.htm) show the following NTP properties:

> ```
> URI: /redfish/v1/Managers/1/Oem/Supermicro/NTP
> Method: PATCH
> Payload:
> {
>     "NTPEnable": true,
>     "PrimaryNTPServer":"127.0.0.1",
>     "SecondaryNTPServer":"127.0.0.1",
>     "DaylightSavingTime": false
> }
> ```

But with the following Ansible tasks:

```yaml
- name: Get services info
  community.general.redfish_info:
    category: Manager
    command: GetNetworkProtocols
    baseuri: "{{ baseuri }}"
    username: "{{ username }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
  register: result

- debug:
    var: result
```

you will get different NTP properties:

```yaml
...
NTPServers:
- 127.0.0.1
- 127.0.0.1
NTPServers@odata.count: 2
ProtocolEnabled: true
...
```

And this time it is a win for redfish_info as it turns out you have to use the properties from its output. Example:

```yaml
- name: Set NTP
  community.general.redfish_config:
    category: Manager
    command: SetNetworkProtocols
    network_protocols:
      NTPServers:
        - 127.0.0.1
        - 127.0.0.1
      ProtocolEnabled: true
    baseuri: "{{ baseuri }}"
    username: "{{ username }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
```

## Further reading

Besides the examples of the Ansible modules, you can get more examples here:

- https://github.com/DMTF/Redfish-Ansible-Playbooks

Answer (score 2):

> *Supermicro offers this Redfish Reference Guide, which describes its Redfish REST API in detail.*

Right. According the documentation you've referenced, Ch. 4 "*Using RESTful APIs*" p. 13 ff., the structure of the REST API call seems to be

```sh
https://${URL}/redfish/v1/${CATEGORY} ...
```

followed by further actions, commands, tasks or payloads.

> *Can someone explain how to map the API options to the Ansible modules?*

After looking up the module documentation examples and the source code

- [`plugins/modules/redfish_config.py`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/modules/redfish_config.py)
- [`plugins/modules/redfish_command.py`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/modules/redfish_command.py)

it turns out that the modules using

- [`plugins/module_utils/redfish_utils.py`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/module_utils/redfish_utils.py)

as a wrapper the utilize the REST API. It maps the REST API structure to the parameter structure of the modules (`category`, `command`, `payload`). For a better understanding you may have a look into the mentioned source.

> *How can I use the Ansible modules to set the hostname or to provide NTP settings?*

[According the source](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/module_utils/redfish_utils.py#L2729) it seems to be the `manager_services` for NTP. Because of the lack of the specific environment I'm not able to investigate this further and to do tests, therefore for how to use it you may also have a look into the source.

To get familar with the Redfish RESTful API you may also have a look into [DMTF Redfishtool](https://github.com/DMTF/Redfishtool) it

> *was originally written during the development of the Redfish specification to help find ambiguities in the spec.*

**Further Examples**

There are some explanations and a general programming example from a bigger production environment available

- Krenn Wiki [Redfish](https://www-thomas--krenn-com.translate.goog/de/wiki/Redfish?_x_tr_sl=de&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=wapp)

**Documentation**

- [Redfish User Guide](https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP2060_1.0.0.pdf)